# React-native - iOS - Module name prefixes error with RCTJSCExecutor

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, react-native

I'm getting an error in one project in react-native (I've tried init'ing new projects and it's not happening in those).  The build succeeds, the simulator loads, the default loading screen shows briefly, then I get the red screen of frustration with the following error:

Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: Module name prefixes should've been stripped by the native side but wasn't for RCTJSCExecutor.

I've tried the solutions here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10585

No luck.

I've deleted/reinstalled node_modules - No luck.
Cleared xcode cache in ~/library/developer/xcode/deriveddata.  No luck.
Cleard /var/folders. No luck.
I've run react-native upgrade. No luck.

Other members on the team aren't experiencing this, and we have the same codebase.

Versions:
OSX: 10.11.6
Xcode: 8.2.1
Node: 7.6.0
Npm: 4.1.2
React-Native: 0.33.1
React-Native-CLI: 2.0.1

Answer (score -2):

stop terminal, and re-run `react-native run-ios`